# how to fetch data from JSON using retrofit?

Tags: android, json, api, retrofit, retrofit2

I want to fetch all these data including "scorecard", "ball by ball", "wickets", "lineups" but sometimes "scorecard" and "ball by ball" are null. If I removed "scorecard", "ball by ball", "wickets", "lineups" from Model class then the code is working properly but I want to fetch data from "scorecard", "ball by ball", "wickets", "lineups". How to solve this problem

JSON:

```
 {
"success": 1,
"result": [
{
  "event_key": "6549",
  "event_date_start": "2021-08-12",
  "event_date_stop": "2021-08-16",
  "event_time": "12:00",
  "event_home_team": "England",
  "home_team_key": "34",
  "event_away_team": "India",
  "away_team_key": "30",
  "event_service_home": "Batting team",
  "event_service_away": "Bowling team",
  "event_home_final_result": "391 (128)",
  "event_away_final_result": "364",
  "event_home_rr": "",
  "event_away_rr": "",
  "event_status": "After day 3",
  "event_status_info": "England lead by 27 runs.",
  "country_name": "World",
  "league_name": "Test Series",
  "league_key": "9846",
  "league_round": "",
  "league_season": "2021",
  "event_live": "1",
  "event_home_team_logo": "https://allsportsapi.com/logo-cricket/34_england.png",
  "event_away_team_logo": "https://allsportsapi.com/logo-cricket/30_india.png",
  "scorecard": {
    "ENG - 1st Innings": [
      {
        "innings": "IND - 1st Innings",
        "player": "Sharma R. / Rahul L.",
        "type": "Partnership",
        "status": "",
        "pos": "1",
        "R": "126",
        "B": "263",
        "Min": "182",
        "SR": "47.91"
      },
      {
        "innings": "IND - 1st Innings",
        "player": "Pujara C. / Rahul L.",
        "type": "Partnership",
        "status": "",
        "pos": "2",
        "R": "24",
        "B": "38",
        "Min": "32",
        "SR": "63.16"
      },
    ]
  },
  "ball_by_ball": {
    "IND - 1st Innings": [
      {
        "innings": "IND - 1st Innings",
        "nr": "127",
        "balls": "W",
        "runs": "0",
        "bowler_to_batsma": "Wood M. to Jadeja R."
      },
      {
        "innings": "IND - 1st Innings",
        "nr": "126",
        "balls": ".|1|.|.|.|W",
        "runs": "1",
        "bowler_to_batsma": "Anderson J. to Jadeja R. & Bumrah J."
      },
    ],
    "ENG - 1st Innings": [
      {
        "innings": "ENG - 1st Innings",
        "nr": "16",
        "balls": ".|.",
        "runs": "0",
        "bowler_to_batsma": "Shami M. to Root J."
      },
      {
        "innings": "ENG - 1st Innings",
        "nr": "15",
        "balls": ".|W|W|.|1|.",
        "runs": "1",
        "bowler_to_batsma": "Siraj M. to Sibley D., Hameed H., Root J. & Burns R."
      },
    ]
  },
  "wickets": {
    "IND - 1st Innings": [
      {
        "innings": "IND - 1st Innings",
        "fall": "125.6 ov",
        "balwer": "Bumrah J.",
        "batsman": "c Buttler J. b Anderson J.",
        "score": "364/9"
      },
      {
        "innings": "IND - 1st Innings",
        "fall": "126.1 ov",
        "balwer": "Jadeja R.",
        "batsman": "c Anderson J. b Wood M.",
        "score": "364/10"
      }
    ],
    "ENG - 1st Innings": [
      {
        "innings": "ENG - 1st Innings",
        "fall": "14.2 ov",
        "balwer": "Sibley D.",
        "batsman": "c Rahul L. b Siraj M.",
        "score": "23/1"
      },
      {
        "innings": "ENG - 1st Innings",
        "fall": "14.3 ov",
        "balwer": "Hameed H.",
        "batsman": "b Siraj M.",
        "score": "23/2"
      },
    ]
  },
  "extra": [
    
  ],
  "lineups": {
    "home_team": {
      "starting_lineups": [
        {
          "player": "Burns R.",
          "player_country": "England"
        },
        {
          "player": "Sibley D.",
          "player_country": "England"
        },
        {
          "player": "Anderson J.",
          "player_country": "England"
        }
      ],
      "coaches": [
        {
          "coache": "Silverwood C.",
          "coache_country": "England"
        }
      ]
    },
    "away_team": {
      "starting_lineups": [
        {
          "player": "Sharma R.",
          "player_country": "India"
        },
        {
          "player": "Rahul L.",
          "player_country": "India"
        },
        {
          "player": "Siraj M.",
          "player_country": "India"
        }
      ],
      "coaches": [
        {
          "coache": "Shastri R.",
          "coache_country": "India"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
},
 {
  "event_key": "6549",
  "event_date_start": "2021-08-12",
  "event_date_stop": "2021-08-16",
  "event_time": "12:00",
  "event_home_team": "Pakistan",
  "home_team_key": "34",
  "event_away_team": "India",
  "away_team_key": "30",
  "event_service_home": "Batting team",
  "event_service_away": "Bowling team",
  "event_home_final_result": "391 (128)",
  "event_away_final_result": "364",
  "event_home_rr": "",
  "event_away_rr": "",
  "event_status": "After day 3",
  "event_status_info": "England lead by 27 runs.",
  "country_name": "World",
  "league_name": "Test Series",
  "league_key": "9846",
  "league_round": "",
  "league_season": "2021",
  "event_live": "1",
  "event_home_team_logo": "https://allsportsapi.com/logo-cricket/34_england.png",
  "event_away_team_logo": "https://allsportsapi.com/logo-cricket/30_india.png",
  "scorecard": {
    "ENG - 1st Innings": [
      {
        "innings": "IND - 1st Innings",
        "player": "Sharma R. / Rahul L.",
        "type": "Partnership",
        "status": "",
        "pos": "1",
        "R": "126",
        "B": "263",
        "Min": "182",
        "SR": "47.91"
      },
      {
        "innings": "IND - 1st Innings",
        "player": "Pujara C. / Rahul L.",
        "type": "Partnership",
        "status": "",
        "pos": "2",
        "R": "24",
        "B": "38",
        "Min": "32",
        "SR": "63.16"
      },
    ],
   "PAK- 1st Innings": [
      {
        "innings": "IND - 1st Innings",
        "player": "Sharma R. / Rahul L.",
        "type": "Partnership",
        "status": "",
        "pos": "1",
        "R": "126",
        "B": "263",
        "Min": "182",
        "SR": "47.91"
      },
      {
        "innings": "IND - 1st Innings",
        "player": "Pujara C. / Rahul L.",
        "type": "Partnership",
        "status": "",
        "pos": "2",
        "R": "24",
        "B": "38",
        "Min": "32",
        "SR": "63.16"
      },
    ]
  },
  "ball_by_ball": {
    "PAK- 1st Innings": [
      {
        "innings": "IND - 1st Innings",
        "nr": "127",
        "balls": "W",
        "runs": "0",
        "bowler_to_batsma": "Wood M. to Jadeja R."
      },
      {
        "innings": "IND - 1st Innings",
        "nr": "126",
        "balls": ".|1|.|.|.|W",
        "runs": "1",
        "bowler_to_batsma": "Anderson J. to Jadeja R. & Bumrah J."
      },
    ],
    "ENG - 1st Innings": [
      {
        "innings": "ENG - 1st Innings",
        "nr": "16",
        "balls": ".|.",
        "runs": "0",
        "bowler_to_batsma": "Shami M. to Root J."
      },
      {
        "innings": "ENG - 1st Innings",
        "nr": "15",
        "balls": ".|W|W|.|1|.",
        "runs": "1",
        "bowler_to_batsma": "Siraj M. to Sibley D., Hameed H., Root J. & Burns R."
      },
    ]
  },
  "wickets": {
    "PAK- 1st Innings": [
      {
        "innings": "IND - 1st Innings",
        "fall": "125.6 ov",
        "balwer": "Bumrah J.",
        "batsman": "c Buttler J. b Anderson J.",
        "score": "364/9"
      },
      {
        "innings": "IND - 1st Innings",
        "fall": "126.1 ov",
        "balwer": "Jadeja R.",
        "batsman": "c Anderson J. b Wood M.",
        "score": "364/10"
      }
    ],
    "ENG - 1st Innings": [
      {
        "innings": "ENG - 1st Innings",
        "fall": "14.2 ov",
        "balwer": "Sibley D.",
        "batsman": "c Rahul L. b Siraj M.",
        "score": "23/1"
      },
      {
        "innings": "ENG - 1st Innings",
        "fall": "14.3 ov",
        "balwer": "Hameed H.",
        "batsman": "b Siraj M.",
        "score": "23/2"
      },
    ]
  },
  "extra": [
    
  ],
  "lineups": {
    "home_team": {
      "starting_lineups": [
        {
          "player": "Burns R.",
          "player_country": "England"
        },
        {
          "player": "Sibley D.",
          "player_country": "England"
        },
        {
          "player": "Anderson J.",
          "player_country": "England"
        }
      ],
      "coaches": [
        {
          "coache": "Silverwood C.",
          "coache_country": "England"
        }
      ]
    },
    "away_team": {
      "starting_lineups": [
        {
          "player": "Sharma R.",
          "player_country": "India"
        },
        {
          "player": "Rahul L.",
          "player_country": "India"
        },
        {
          "player": "Siraj M.",
          "player_country": "India"
        }
      ],
      "coaches": [
        {
          "coache": "Shastri R.",
          "coache_country": "India"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
},
 {
  "event_key": "7086",
  "event_date_start": "2021-08-14",
  "event_date_stop": "2021-08-14",
  "event_time": "12:00",
  "event_home_team": "Essex",
  "home_team_key": "207",
  "event_away_team": "Yorkshire",
  "away_team_key": "209",
  "event_service_home": "Bowling team",
  "event_service_away": "Batting team",
  "event_home_final_result": "317/7 (50)",
  "event_away_final_result": "188/10 (38.4)",
  "event_home_rr": "RR 6.34",
  "event_away_rr": "RR 4.86",
  "event_status": "YOR Innings",
  "event_status_info": "Yorkshire require another 130 runs.",
  "country_name": "United Kingdom",
  "league_name": "One-Day Cup",
  "league_key": "9816",
  "league_round": "Quarter-finals",
  "league_season": "2021",
  "event_live": "1",
  "event_home_team_logo": "https://allsportsapi.com/logo-cricket/207_essex.png",
  "event_away_team_logo": "https://allsportsapi.com/logo-cricket/209_yorkshire.png",
  "scorecard": [
  ],
  "ball_by_ball": [
  ],
  "wickets": [
  ],
  "extra": [
  ],
  "lineups": {
    "home_team": {
      "starting_lineups": [
      ],
      "coaches": [
      ]
    },
    "away_team": {
      "starting_lineups": [
      ],
      "coaches": [
      ]
    }
  }
}
]
}
```

This is my code:

```
     APIInterface apiInterface = Retrofit.getRetrofit().create(APIInterface.class);
    Call<LiveMatchDetail> liveMatches = apiInterface.getLiveMatches("API_KEY");
    liveMatches.enqueue(new Callback<LiveMatchDetail>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<LiveMatchDetail> call, Response<LiveMatchDetail> response)
        {
            Log.e("live ---", "onSuccess: " + response.body());
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Live Success!  " + response.body(), 
  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            LiveMatchDetail liveMatches = response.body();
            List<LiveMatchDetail.Result> list = liveMatches.getResult();
 }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<LiveMatchDetail> call, Throwable t)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Live Failure!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Log.e("live ---", "onFailure: " + t.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

And, I'm getting this error:

```
 onFailure: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 47320 path $.result[2].scorecard
```

Model class link:

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-EQPbzqPh6bBT93SyG2ajAVz2SRfR8CQ/view?usp=sharing
```

Comment: Please share your LiveMatchDetail Data Class

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-EQPbzqPh6bBT93SyG2ajAVz2SRfR8CQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The error message says it was expecting an object, but its an array at that particular line and column number. Try using json lint and see if your json is valid. And also make sure your model class correctly matches the structure.

Comment: Check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68792797/11888547)

Answer (score 1):

```
Call<List<LiveMatchDetail>> liveMatches = apiInterface.getLiveMatches("API_KEY");
```

Try this, basically expect the Response as `List<LiveMatchDetail>` not `LiveMatchDetail`